# no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.14393 in the manifest list entries for dotnet/aspnet:3.1 in Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-devops

I was trying to build the docker image in AzureDevOps.
However on release pipeline I receive below error message while building the docker imamge:

```
Step 1/30 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
3.1: Pulling from dotnet/aspnet
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.14393 in the manifest list entries
```

I have checked in Docker Hub, that `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1` is the latest available image.

Reference from: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet

And I have build the image in local, it was build succeeded without any problem.
Below are my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT #{environment-profile}#

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Api/Api.csproj", "Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Api/Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api"
RUN dotnet build "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll", "--environment=#{environment-profile}#"]
```

Is there anything that I missed to cause that it couldn't found the image?

Appreciate if anyone could help. Thank you.

Comment: As I know, some windows container image need new os version to support, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57406489/no-matching-manifest-for-unknown-in-the-manifest-list-entries-when-pull-nanose, if possible the azure used an old windows? As you said it's ok to build it in your local...

Comment: I'm not sure which OS version is the Azure running on... Is there anyway to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok found the problem... The agent job in Azure DevOps should be changed to Linux. I changed to Ubuntu16.04 then it works.